# Page properties not being properly initialised in onCreationCompleted, Blackberry 10

Tags: properties, qml, blackberry-10

I am initialising the properties of one QML page from another.

The code for my first QML page - `page1.qml`  is as follows:

```
Page{
    id: page1

    //Some code

    Button{
        text: "Click Me"
        onClicked: {
             var page = nextPage.createObject();
             page.cost = netCost;  //netCost is an int property of page1 and is calculated in the code
             resvNav.push(page);  //resNav is the id of the NavigationPane
        }
    }// Button ends

    attachedObjects: [
         ComponentDefinition {
              id: nextPage
              source: "page2.qml"
         }
    ]
}// page ends
```

The code for my second page - `page2.qml` is as follows:

```
Page{
   id: page2

   property int cost
   property alias labeltext: label1.text
   Container{
      Label{
         id: label1
      }
   }// Container ends

   onCreationCompleted{
       console.debug(cost);
       var totalCost = cost + 50;
       labeltext = totalCost;
   }
}//Page ends
```

Now, the problem is that for whatever value of `cost` passed from `page1.qml` to `page2.qml` it's value as shown in console is always 0 and thus `totalCost` always comes out to be 50. 
When I use the code `label1.text: cost`, then it shows the correct value of the property.

Are properties not initialised when used in `onCreationCompleted`? If not, then what is the method to use and/or modify properties once the page has been pushed? I tried calling a custom javascript function from `onCreationCompleted` but it yielded the same result, i.e., `cost` remained 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code

```
var page = nextPage.createObject();
page.cost = netCost;
```

You are creating page using `createObject`. `onCreationCompleted` will be called when `createObject` is finished. That time cost is 0, so totalCost will be 50.

And then you are assigning cost value by `page.cost = netCost;`

So if you want to calculate correct total cost value then you should implement `onCostChanged()` handler and move code from `onCreationCompleted` to this handler.